# отсутствие CORS заголовков при запросе в api.telegram.com

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, cors

пишу тг бот,пользователь загружает картинку, бот выкидывает ссылку и эта ссылка используется для вывода изображения на фронтенде. ссылку бот отдает и с этим все нормально, но как только делаю запрос с фронтенда, выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: 
Политика одного источника запрещает чтение 
удаленного ресурса на https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<filePath>
(Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»).
Код состояния: 200.
```

**код запроса:**

```
const [photoUrl, setPhotoUrl] = useState('');
    const [isLoaded, setIsloaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot${token}/${filePath}`,
            responseType: 'stream'
        }).then((res) => {
            const photoBlob = new Blob([res]);
            console.log(res)
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(photoBlob);
            setPhotoUrl(url);
            setIsloaded(true);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }, []);
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` это вроде как серверная часть... https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-crossorigin#shag-4-osnovnoy-otvet